# Facebook follow functionality using Firebase

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, facebook, firebase

I'm building a social network like Strava using Firebase server.
I want to search other users via name and want to show the follow/following button on the list view. 
But I'm little confused to run iOS firebase queries for searching the followed friends and those not followed when I load the view. 
Below is my database structure for the user/follow table.

[image: database]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you having exactly?

Comment: i am not sure if i understand correctly, but that structure cannot really work. use_followed should not be an object, it should be an array. right now, a user can only follow one other user, right?

Comment: no I need that one user can follow multiple users

Comment: @luschn Arrays should generally be avoided in NoSQL Databases [Arrays are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) but I think your point is the user_followed should be a series of nodes that contain multiple nodes of references to other users - like this: *user_followed/uid_0: true* and *user_followed/uid_1: true* etc.

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the users that are following a specific user, and those users id's are stored in the user_followed node? So in the structure in your question you want to get the users that are following the user Vale?